# Why the Ajax content of this jQuery plugin (Tooltipster) is shown only after mouse hover 2 times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tooltipster

I can't find a solution for this [plugin](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) since I cannot find any working demo or documentation for external content via Ajax.

Basically I have a simple `div` with a mouse hover JS function:

```
<div onmouseover="myFunct(this,'.$comment['id'].');"  >Hover Me</div>
```

And this is my JS function:

```
function myFunct(element, id){

    $(element).tooltipster({
        contentCloning: true,
        interactive:true,
        maxWidth:250,
        contentAsHTML:true,
        content: 'Loading...',

        // 'instance' is basically the tooltip. More details in the "Object-oriented Tooltipster" section.
        functionBefore: function(instance, helper) {

            var $origin = $(helper.origin);

            // we set a variable so the data is only loaded once via Ajax, not every time the tooltip opens
            if ($origin.data('loaded') !== true) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: baseUrl+"/requests/load_profilecard.php",
                    data: 'id='+id+"&token_id="+token_id,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {           
                    // call the 'content' method to update the content of our tooltip with the returned data
                    instance.content(html);

                    // to remember that the data has been loaded
                    $origin.html('loaded', true);
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**Why the tooltip is shown only at the 2nd mouse hover?**

Here is a similar Eg. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xx5n1xa/1/)

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the support this has solved my issue:

```
<div class="tooltip" data-id="'.$comment['id'].'">Hover me!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
        content: 'Loading...',
        functionBefore: function(instance, helper){
            var $origin = $(helper.origin);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl+"/requests/load_profilecard.php",
                data: 'id='+ $origin.attr('data-id')+"&token_id="+token_id,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {           
                    // call the 'content' method to update the content of our tooltip with the returned data
                    instance.content(html);

                }
            });   
        },
        interactive:true,
        contentAsHTML:true,
        maxWidth:250
    });
});
</script>
```

Anyway this doesn't work on Ajax dynamic content, and I don't know why (I tried to insert it on Ajax page, no way)

Comment: What happens when you remove the `if`? I am wondering if the condition fails on the first hover but then passes on the second.

Comment: @KennethStoddard Thanks, already tried but it's the same, same issue. This is from Tooltipster support - "you initialize your tooltip when the mouseover event has already been fired, so Tooltipster cannot "hear" this first event and open the tooltip. You'd better initialize your tooltips at page load and put your comment id in a data-id attribute that you'll retrieve in functionBefore when you prepare your ajax call."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend a few things: first, separate your JS from your HTML (this is considered best practice), second, initialize Tooltipster on page load, and last, remove the wrapper function. Once the tooltip is initialized your code will trigger by default on hover.

**Separate JS from HTML**

```
<div class="hover-me tool-tip" data-commentId="12345">Hover Me</div>
```

**Initalize Tooltipster on Document Ready**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
});
```

**Trigger Tooltipster with Hover**

```
$('.hover-me').tooltipster({
    // all of your code from above

    functionBefore: function(){
        var commentId = $(this).attr('data-commentId');
    }
});
```

**Note:**

The default trigger for Tooltipster is `hover` (as seen in the documentation), however, you could explicitly set it by passing in `trigger: hover`, which would make your code slightly more readable and as such maintainable.

**Tooltipster Support Recommendation (as seen in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793656/why-the-ajax-content-of-this-jquery-plugin-tooltipster-is-shown-only-after-mou#comment-64967426))**

I add this because it reinforces my solution above and adds context for future devs...that, and it might be overlooked in the comments section.

> You initialize your tooltip when the mouseover event has already been fired, so Tooltipster cannot "hear" this first event and open the tooltip. You'd better initialize your tooltips at page load and put your comment id in a data-id attribute that you'll retrieve in functionBefore when you prepare your ajax call.

Comment: You are missing only one thing, the `data-id` attribute...I suppose something like this right? `var commentID = $(this).attr('data-id');`

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right, answer updated. The only other thing (which I personally haven't had the chance to validate) is accessing `this` from inside of the `instance` param on `functionBefore`. It the above doesn't work try that.

Comment: The third snippet should be corrected, see https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/585#issuecomment-238013953

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, what needs to be corrected? Thanks

Comment: It should be something like 
```$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
        functionBefore: function(instance, helper){
            var $origin = $(helper.origin),
                commentId = $origin.attr('data-id');
        }
    });```

Comment: @Evan on Ajax dynamic content it doesn't work, I tried searching online and I can't find any help. Could you please give me the final hint to make it works? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, see correction. You can just grab the value of the data attribute from with the `functionBefore` by doing this ... `var commentId = $(this).attr('data-commentId');`. You can then do this ... `data: 'id='+ commentId+"&token_id="+token_id`

Comment: using this way var commentId is undefined