# Dynamic content not shown after Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tooltipster

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793656/why-the-ajax-content-of-this-jquery-plugin-tooltipster-is-shown-only-after-mou) one.
I'm using Tooltipster JQuery plugin to show tooltips on my website like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="tooltip" data-id="'.$comment['id'].'">Hover me!</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
        content: 'Loading...',
        functionBefore: function(instance, helper){
            var $origin = $(helper.origin);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl+"/requests/load_profilecard.php",
                data: 'id='+ $origin.attr('data-id')+"&token_id="+token_id,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {           
                    // call the 'content' method to update the content of our tooltip with the returned data
                    instance.content(html);

                }
            });   
        },
        interactive:true,
        contentAsHTML:true,
        maxWidth:250
    });
});
</script>
```

Anyway this doesn't work on Ajax dynamic content, basically I load via Ajax new content with a function:

```
function exploreTracks(start, filter) {
    $('#load-more').html('<div class="load_more" style="height: 232px;"><div class="preloader-loadmore preloader-center"></div></div>');

    if(filter == '') {
        q = '';
    } else {
        q = '&filter='+filter;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl+"/requests/load_explore.php",
        data: "start="+start+q+"&token_id="+token_id, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $('#load-more').remove();

            // Append the new comment to the div id
            $('#main-content').append(html);

            // Reload the timeago plugin
            jQuery("div.timeago").timeago();
            // Update the Track Information
            updateTrackInfo(nowPlaying);
        }
    });
}
```

New contents on mouse hover don't show any tooltip, from console I can't see any error or warning and on network `load_profilecard.php` is not called.

I have placed the script (same JS as above) directly on my content page, so why the tooltip is not shown on mouse hover?

**My solution**

As suggested in comments by Evan I used [delegation](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#delegation) option for this purpose.

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('mouseenter', '.tooltip:not(.tooltipstered)', function(){
        $(this)
            .tooltipster({      
            content: 'Loading...',
            functionBefore: function(instance, helper){
                var $origin = $(helper.origin);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: baseUrl+"/requests/load_profilecard.php",
                    data: 'id='+ $origin.attr('data-id')+"&token_id="+token_id,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {           
                        // call the 'content' method to update the content of our tooltip with the returned data
                        instance.content(html);

                    }
                });   
            },
            interactive:true,
            contentAsHTML:true,
            maxWidth:250 })
        .tooltipster('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you have to change `function(html)` to `funcion(data)` in success

Comment: Besides, what's the event to trigger the ajax? I don't c onclick nor any other event

Comment: @developerbh I tried `funcion(data)` but it's the same. This JQuery plugin trigger on hover by default `$('.tooltip').tooltipster({`

Comment: That's expected. You need to initialize new tooltips when you create new HTML elements, or go the delegation way. Read about delegation in the documentation: http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#delegation